# Как из шаблона Item'a привязаться к самому Item?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

вот кусочек кода

```
<ListBox Name="icArrows" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Arrows}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <ItemsControl.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <controls:SchemaArrow Width="50" Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PlanItemToArrowHeightConverter}}"/>
```

Проблема в том, что в последней строке в конвертер приходит экземпляр `SchemaArrow`, хотя `Arrows` - это коллекция экземпляров другого типа данных (`PlatItem`). Именно `PlatItem` мне и нужен в конвертере

Дополнение к вопросу:

Ну и еще кое что меня ввело в недоумение. Вот полный код `ListBox`

```
<ListBox Name="icArrows" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Arrows}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <controls:SchemaArrow Width="50" Height="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PlanItemToArrowHeightConverter}}"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PlanItemToCanvasPositionConverter}" ConverterParameter="top">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}"/>
                        <Binding/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PlanItemToCanvasPositionConverter}" ConverterParameter="left">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}"/>
                        <Binding/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```

Там есть мультиконвертеры, а вот в них уже `<Binding/>` передает в конвертер именно `PlanItem`. Странно все это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно определить не ControTemplate, а DataTemplate.

```
 <ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <!-- ваш контрол с привязанными данными, например:-->
            <controls:MyControl Context="{Binding PlatItem}" />
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```